# how to write 1-D array in multiple columns with pythons

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to write a 1-D array to file in several columns with savetxt in Python. I did not find the option that allows that. Say for instance I have a 1-D array of 13 elements and I want to write in 5 columns, like this:

```
1  2  3  4  5

6  7  8  9  10

11 12
```

I am using:

```
np.savetxt('temp_test.dat',x,fmt='%11.9e',delimiter=',',newline=' ')
```

How can I specify the number of columns?

Thanks

Anthony

Comment: You will need to reshape your array `x` before saving. If you intend to use `numpy.loadtxt` later, then this is a bad idea. If not, reshape away!

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a chunk size and loop:

```
orig_a = np.arange(1, 14)
chunk_size = 5
i = 0
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    a = orig_a[i * chunk_size:(i + 1) * chunk_size]

    while len(a):
        a = orig_a[i * chunk_size:(i + 1) * chunk_size]
        np.savetxt(f, a[np.newaxis], fmt='%d')
        i += 1
```

gives:

```
In [14]: cat test.txt
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13
```

Note that for arrays with many rows this will be inefficient.